# what version of nvidia-cg does ogre want?

Tags: ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install desktop-full on a FC15 machine. I installed the latest version of Cg from nvidia's website, and ogre gives me this when I try to rosmake:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../libCg.so when searching for -lCg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10827/what-version-of-nvidia-cg-does-ogre-want?/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like you downloaded a 32-bit version of Cg but are running 64-bit linux. Can you make sure you downloaded the version of Cg that matches your Linux architecture (32bit vs 64bit). Also, have you tried just running `rosdep install ogre`. It looks like rosdep does have an entry for Fedora for nvidia-cg, so that would probably be your best bet for getting a compatible version of nvidia-cg.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-08-04**:
I'm not sure what the rosdep for nvidia-cg is supposed to refer to, but yum doesn't know anything about Cg. Removing and reinstalling the rpm from nvidia seems to have resolved the problem.